# Error: Cannot redeclare class in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp. I have a class called Rest that is shared by two controllers: Pages and Categories.

I therefore thought of making the instance of the class in the AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $rest;


    public function DoRest() {
        require 'Component/Rest.php';

        if(!isset($this->rest))
        $this -> rest = new Rest();

        return $this -> rest;
    }
}
```

then i can access it at the categoriesController:

```
public function index() 
    {
        if ($this->request->is('requested')) {
            return $this -> DoRest() -> getCategories();
        } else {
            $this -> set('categories', $this -> DoRest() -> getCategories());
        }
    }
```

and in the pages controller:

```
public function category() {

        $this -> set('items',$this -> DoRest() -> getCategoryById($this->request->query['id']));
    }
```

within category.ctp i can access the categories through:

```
$categories = $this->requestAction('categories/index');
```

however now im getting this error:
`Error: Cannot redeclare class Rest`

What have i done wrong?

Comment: just now, didn't solve it :(

Comment: @nlsbshtr i got it, there was a  file inside the Rest class with a require as well. After chancing that to require_once 'PestXML.php'; solved the error. But still, it appears the Rest class get's called twice though it's called in the AppController. How should i prevent that that both the categories and pages use the same Rest instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve a couple of issues. First, you’re not including files the “Cake” way; and second you’re not naming components the “Cake” way either.

Components should be suffixed as such. So your Rest component should look like this:

```
<?php
class RestComponent extends Component {
}
```

Secondly, components should then be loaded in your controller via the relavant property:

```
<?php
class YourController extends AppControler {
    public $components = array('Rest');
}
```

Everything should then work. However, I’d question your need to create a Rest component at all. CakePHP has built-in [REST handling](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html), and also a [HTTP component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html) for making requests to third-party services via HTTP.

Comment: aah more comprehensive then the other one. I have to be fair and accept this one :) Thanks for the info and the tip about rest handling, I'll adjust it likewise.

Comment: No problem. Cake’s a lovely framework once you get adept with it. Stay with it!

Comment: yeah indeed, it works quite well. I'm actually still a bit confused what model stands for. Is it like the same as a Java Bean? Like a pojo class? I noticed it's totally different as in Model with C# Mvc...

Comment: where does the business logic need to go? to the controller or the component?

Comment: I’m not familiar with Java, but a model is part of the MVC paradigm (which Cake follows) and quite similar to Rails. A model represents a database table and allows you save and retrieve data to and from your database. Start reading through the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) as that will get you up to speed on Cake’s principles and best practices.

Comment: Oh, and business logic goes in the model, as the model could be used in multiple controllers, so you would put it in the model to keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'Component/Rest.php';
```

Thats not how its done in cake. Please read the documentation. If anything you use App::uses().

But with components you should just follow the official way:

```
public $components = array('Rest');
```

and the component class file should be named RestComponent.php, again as documented.

If you are using something else, its not a component, but a lib and requires the above app::uses() (place your file in /Lib folder then):

```
App::uses('Rest', 'Lib');
```